# Weird GC with endtime = 0L and duration = 0L

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Recently, I just got this problem in the log file, there is a log for the GC and its endtime is 0L, and duration is 0L too, I do not quite understand how this kind of GC could ever occur (endtime zero would indicate it occurred right at the same time when JVM starts), this does not actually look like a real GC . Also I use `GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo` to get the data of the GC occurred, and before this weird GC, we have some normal GC with a positive end time and positive duration. So in a word, I do not understand two things here:

1. This GC with endtime = 0L and duration = 0L looks like not a real GC, then what is it?
2. If this GC is not a real GC, why do we get a notification of GARBAGE_COLLECTION_NOTIFICATION type for it? Anyone can enlighten me a bit?

Alright, caught this GC again, more info:

```
GC Name: ConcurrentMarkSweep 
GC Cause: Allocation Failure
GC Action: end of major GC 
GC started at: 0 ms since JVM started
GC ended at: 0 ms since JVM started
GC duration: 0 ms 
The number of collections that this collector has done: 0
```

Comment: Please share your error message.

Comment: Your error message share please.

Comment: Sorry, there is no error message at all, I just log the end time and duration for every gc occurred which were directly obtained from GCInfo class

Comment: You need to show us the entire `GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo` contents. There are more than just the `GCInfo`. What's `getGcAction` for example? suppose you're using `GarbageCollectorMXBean`? Are you verifying the notification type is `GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo.GARBAGE_COLLECTION_NOTIFICATION` ? These details matter.

Comment: Thanks guys, but unfortunately I did not log other information from GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo except the endtime and the duration, I did check the notification type of GARBAGE_COLLECTION_NOTIFICATION though, I am afraid I am not able to provide those info